# Reading an unknown number of items in a web drop down list and storing in an array

Tags: java

I would like code to store an unknown number of integer values from a website's drop-down list into an array and then compare the values in an existing array with the array values retrieved from the drop-down list.

I was thinking maybe a For loop could work? I apologize but I don't have any sample code to put up because I don't know how to start with creating this code. I do have Basic Java knowledge

Comment: Try ArrayList, it should help.

Comment: You can create `ArrayList` of type that you required and then using `.add()` method add that to the `ArrayList` and then you can loop through them using the `foreach(ListItem typeItem in ArrayListName)` hope this should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arraylists, they are dynamic and don't have to be specified size in advance unlike arrays.

```
 List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You can add to `integers` by `integers.add();`